# NSStoryboard and Nib doesn't load NSObject if use NSWindowsController

Tags: ios, macos, nswindowcontroller, nsstoryboard, viper-architecture

For work I use Viper-architecture and build module through NSObject that I connect directly via the Storyboard or Nib. This works well, but if you connect through the NSViewController to segue NSWindowsControllers, the application crashes with an error, since it is not called NSObject.
Of course, there is the option to collect the module through the "storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier:)", but I want to use Nibs, and there optionality error.

[So looks NSStoryboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUvzZ.png)

[Example to GitHub](https://github.com/SpectralDragon/ViperTestOSX/tree/master)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @rocky observing the behavior of the program, I realized that the module is going before to load the controller. It turns out that I pull the techniques before they are declared. Now throw off the sample code on github.

Comment: @rocky add example link

Comment: @SpectralDragonChan Hey! Did you solve your problem? I faced with it and wonder is there some workaround for it?